# Javascript change my variable when another one is changed

Tags: javascript

What I need is to save value of on global variable to my global variable once the first one is deffined.

Exactly what I need is:

```
var old_other_global; 
var my_global
if(typeof other_global === "object"){
   old_other_global = other_global;
   my_global = (other_global = "undefined");
}

var d=document,g=d.createElement('script'),s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
g.type='text/javascript';
g.defer=true;
g.async=true;
g.src=u+'some_file.js';
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);

//Set back old value to "other_global"
if(typeof old_other_global === "object"){
    other_global = old_other_global;
}
```

The variable "other_global" is going to be changed in js file "some_file.js" which I am loading on next way:

```
if(typeof other_global != "object")
{  
   //define other_global
}
```

So immediatelly after "some_file.js" change "other_global" variable I need it saved in my global variable "my_global".

Is that possible to do. I don't have access to "some_file.js"

**EDIT:**

I am doing this because of versioning. Variable "other_global" can be set to one version before "some_file.js" is loaded. So I need to save "other_global" to another variable before it's loaded and set it to undefined. Then after "some_file.js" is loaded and change "other_global" I need to save it in my global variable and then reset it with old value (before) "some_file.js" is loaded. I edited the code above.

And I need my variable changed immediatelly after "other_global" is redefined in "some_file.js" I cannot wait until file ends with loading (like script.onload()), because I need to trigger one function call which is made at the end of "some_file.js" and at that point I alrady need "my_global" to have value set.

Comment: If you have access to `other_global` from your own script, why don't you let your code work with `other_global` instead of `my_global`?

Comment: Check my edit for explanation.

Comment: You can't do `g.async=true;` and expect thing to be synchronous.

Comment: Why can't you wait for some_file.js to execute?

Comment: Because at the on "some_file.js" there is call to one function. I need to trigger that call, but at that moment I need "other_global" saved in my global. If I wait for some_file.js to execute then it's too late